Why does the recurrence relation for Euler zigzag numbers lead to the differential equation $2y' = y^2 + 1$
The recurrence relation for Euler zigzag numbers is given by
$$
2E_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} E_k E_{n-k}, \quad \text{for } n \geq 1
$$
If we set
$$
y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$
Then
$$
y'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \frac{x^{(n-1)}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E_{n+1} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}
$$
And plugging in the recurrence relation we get
$$
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} E_k E_{n-k} \right) \frac{x^{n}}{n!}
$$
Which is the Cauchy product
$$
= \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E_n \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) = \frac{1}{2} y^2(x)
$$
Hence we get the differential equation $2y' = y^2$, but that is wrong, we are missing a +1 term. What am I doing wrong here?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation#Andr%C3%A9's_theorem

The problem is that the recursion only works for $n>0$. Thus, you actually get $y(x)^2 + 2E_1 -E_0^2= 2y'(x).$ Thus $2y'(x) = y(x)^2 + 1$ iff $2E_1-E_0^2=1$ which is true since $E_0=E_1=1$.

The question is about sequences with intial values $a_0, a_1$ and the
recurrence relation
$$ 2a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_k a_{n-k}, \quad \text{for } n\geq 1. \tag1 $$
This family of sequence is referred to in the
OEIS sequence A289064 with a comment

One of a family of integer sequences whose e.g.f.s satisfy the differential equation f''(z) = f'(z)f(z). Each such sequence is uniquely characterized by its two starting terms. When the first term changes sign, the effect is the inversion of the signs of all even terms, leaving all absolute values intact. There are many related sequences in the OEIS (see the link). Starting with a(0) = a(1) = 1, for example, one obtains A000111. All such sequences have a well defined, explicit e.g.f. (see the link).

The specific sequence OEIS sequence A000111
referred to here is the Euler or up/down or zigzag numbers.
Define the exponential generating function of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ as
$$ y(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}. \tag2 $$
Given the recurrence relation $(1)$ this function satisfies the
ordinary differential equation
$$ 2y'(x) = y(x)^2 + 2a_1 - a_0^2. \tag3 $$
The reason for the constant term $2a_1 - a_0^2 $ is that the recurrence
relation $(1)$ only holds for $n>0$. Another differential equation is
$$ y''(x) = y'(x)y(x) \tag4 $$
which does not depends on the initial values.
